# Laravel model relationship through

Tags: php, laravel, relation, laravel-5.6

I have 3 tables like:

```
| user_table |    | user_image_table|     | images_table |
---------------------------------------------------------- 
  id_user    |    |   id_user       |     |   id_image   |
             |    |   id_image      |     |              |
```

Problem is that if user is logged in I can't get images that belongs to that user. I have tried:

```
hasManyThrough(Image::class, UserImage::class, 'id_user', 'id_image')
```

in `User` class. But this has not helped. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `belongsToMany` relationship in both `Image` and `User` models.

Image model:

```
public function users(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_image_table', 'id_image', 'id_user');
}
```

User model:

```
public function images(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'user_image_table', 'id_user', 'id_image');
}
```

and then access logged in user's images via `Auth::user()->images` or `request()->user()->images`

Comment: nop, doesn't helped. it return just null. Even i write wrong `user_image_table` it shows just null

Comment: can you show me your controller's code? and check the edited version

Comment: i have fixed it. Used your code. Just changed users to: 
`$this->belongsToMany(Image::class, 'user_has_image', 'id_user', 'id_image');`

Comment: I don't understand why we are using users on Image model. Is that for accessing users through images?

Comment: Yes, relations are defined in both ways so that you can query them from anywhere you want. like in this case, if you query all users then you can get their images too and if you query all images then you can get their respective users too.

Comment: Thank you very much. You saved my life :)